# CNN for numeric data

Tags: conv-neural-network

I wanted to use CNN for the classification of my dataset which is numerical dataset. My dataset is 3200x36 size. Whenever I used the following code and passed my data, I did not get any result. For the accuracy, it just runs but do not output anything. What did I do wrong, Please explain.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feature, target, train_size=0.75)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=4))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=8149, verbose=1)
accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print( model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Seems like you're running a 2D Conv Net on 1 dimensional data and then even pool afterwards. You probably want to use 1D Conv or fully connected

Comment: Hello, I tried using 1D too but the same happens, no any result. When I run that accuracy line, the code runs. After that when I want to print the accuracy, it says "name 'accuracy' is not defined". Please help me.

Comment: MaxPool2D might reduce your dim to None since its way too big for the shape of your data

Comment: I removed the pooling line but still got the same problem. Also I used 1D conv. I am not understanding where I did wrong.

Comment: Reduce batch_size in model fit to something like 32 or 64, your batch size is bigger than your dataset

Comment: I used batch size of 32 but still the same problem.